# Mittag-Leffler function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, inequalities

Let the Mittaq-Leffler function be defined by the expression
$$ E_{\mu,\nu}(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{\Gamma(k\mu+\nu)}\quad \text{$\mu>0$ and $\nu\in \mathbb R$}$$

Now let $n\in \mathbb N$, $\alpha \in (\frac{n-1}{n},1)$. My question is whether the Mittag-Leffler function $E_{n\alpha,1}(t)$ is non vanishing for all $t<0$ or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. E.g., for $n=2$ and $\alpha=19/20$, we get the following:

[image]

The idea of this example is based on the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function#Special_cases) $E_2(-z^2)=E_{2,1}(-z^2)=\cos z$ and the continuity of $E_{a,1}(t)$ in $a$.

---

More counterexamples can be obtained from the [asymptotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function)
$$E_{a,1}(t)\sim-\frac1{\Gamma(1-a)t}=-\frac{\Gamma(1+a)}{\pi at}\,\sin\pi a$$
as $t\to-\infty$ for $a\in\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(n-1,n)$ and the equality $E_{a,1}(0)=1$.